# What exactly is "scroll position"?

Tags: html, css

What is meant by "scroll position" in HTML and CSS? It probably applies to elements that have a scrollbar, but I'm not certain.

Is it the distance between the outer margin of the topmost child element of an element with a vertical scrollbar, and the top of the visible area? Or the outer margin of the leftmost child element of an element with a horizontal scrollbar, and the left side of the visible area? (And in what unit is it measured?)

"Scroll position" is mentioned in documentation a lot, but after much searching I haven't found an actual definition. I don't mean any specific JS property or CSS rule, because I don't know how they relate.

Comment: You can read this in the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop